# Integrability of the sum of integrable and non-intergable functions

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $\int_\Omega |f_1|\,dx <\infty$ and $\int_\Omega |f_2|\,dx =\infty$, for measurable $f_1,f_2:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. Is it true that
$$
\int_\Omega|f_1+f_2|\,dx=\infty\,?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true. It's imminent from this inequality
$$ |f_2|=|f_2+f_1-f_1|\leq |f_2+f_1|+|f_1| $$